# What is the total number of different sets of natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read that the there are uncountably many different sets of natural numbers. How can you prove that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the power set of the natural numbers countable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77656/is-the-power-set-of-the-natural-numbers-countable) not to mention http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61926/is-the-class-of-subsets-of-integers-countably-infinite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an immediate consequence of Cantor's Theorem, which is proved [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).