# $\mathbb{Q}$ in metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ neither open nor closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ with metric space $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Attempt: So I need to prove two parts.

(a) $\mathbb{Q}$ not open: Take $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Note that $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is arbitrarily small for arbitrarily large $n$, so $q\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\in\mathbb{I}$. Thus for any $r>0$, $B_r(q)$ will contain irrational numbers so $B_r(q)\not\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

(b) $\mathbb{Q}$ not closed: We want to show $\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain all its accumulation points.  $q+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\in\mathbb{I}$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$ but $q+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Recall a closed set is one that contains all of its limit points. Now why does $\mathbb{Q}$ not fit this definition? Because there are cauchy sequences that......

Comment: Revising an earlier comment: Show that the irrationals are dense in the reals, and use the same argument that you used in (a).

Comment: @BenjaminLim But a set in which every Cauchy sequence has a limit in it is called compact. If you take $(0,1)$ as the whole space then this set will have Cauchy sequences (with respect to the standard metric) that converge to $0$ or $1$ and yet this set is closed.

Comment: For $\mathbb{Q}$ not being closed, since it is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, what does that say about $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?  And how does the closure of a closed set compare with the set itself?

Comment: @Matt N.:  I think Benjamin is saying that a set (of reals) $F$ is closed iff whenever $x$ is a _limit point_ of $F$ (meaning that every neighbourhood of $x$ meets $F$ in a point distinct from $x$), then $x \in F$.  Since $\mathbb{R}$ is first-countable, this reduces to saying that $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed iff for every _convergent_ sequence of points of $F$, the limit is also an element of $F$.

Comment: @MattN: No, a metric space in which every Cauchy sequence converges is a *complete* space; in order to be compact, it must be totally bounded as well as complete. $\mathbb{R}$ is complete in the usual metric but is not compact.

Comment: @Arthur: I took Benjamin simply to be suggesting that there are convergent sequences of rationals whose limits aren’t rational; I don’t know whether describing them as Cauchy sequences was inadvertent overcomplication or a deliberate attempt not to say too much.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I meant to write complete there. : S Not compact.

Comment: @BenjaminLim Ignore my comment.

Comment: @MattN. What I meant to say was what Brian said above, sorry if I caused the confusion.

Comment: @BenjaminLim I'm sorry for adding to the confusion!

Comment: A set $O$ is open if and only if $O=\mathrm{Int}(O)$. You can see that $\mathbb{Q}\neq\emptyset$, but $\mathrm{Int}(\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$. To prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't closed, let $(s_n)$ the sequence of the partial sums of the [decimal expansion](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30062/8271) of $\sqrt{2}$. Then $s_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic fact to use is that every open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ contains both rational and irrational numbers (this is just reformulating that both sets are dense, essentially). This means no open set can be contained in just $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{P}$ (the irrationals), so both sets have empty interior, and thus are far from being open.

Comment: Does the fact that no open set can be contained in just $\mathbb{Q}$ imply that $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be open because given any point in $\mathbb{Q}$ an open ball around that point is not a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: "both sets have empty interior, and thus are far from being closed" $\{0\}$ has empty interior and is closed. Did you mean "far from being open"?

Comment: @zulon: is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ also a set with empty interioir? I think he meant: $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ both have empty interiors and are complements of each other $\Rightarrow$ both are far from being open and _closed_.

Comment: @Emir: I did mean open, yes, I was too fast.... thx

Comment: @Emir: yes, that was the argument: there are no interior points at all, because *no* non-empty open subset is a subset of the rationals or the irrationals.

Answer (score 0):

The ball inside Q doesn't fulfill the open set property B(x,r) subset of Q, because of dense property (It has Irrationals inside too)