# $[0,1]$ is uncountable using Baire's Category Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

Given that, $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.
$[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and is closed $\implies [0,1]$ is complete and clearly non-empty.
So we know by BCT: $[0,1]$ is second category.

> Suppose $[0,1]$ is countable, then let $[0,1] = \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{x_n\}$
>   Singletons are closed and have empty interior $\implies$ nowhere dense.
>   So $[0,1]$ is first category by def *Contradiction.

Is this proof concrete enough?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "concrete enough", but the proof is solid.

Comment: Solid enough :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165696/328173 https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141109/328173